# Adding custom permissions to MediaWiki user via user group

Tags: php, mediawiki

I am using mediawiki 1.21.2, I have to create a custom group with limited permissions .
in my LocalSettings.php i have done like this

```
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop' ]['move']           = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop' ]['read']           = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop' ]['edit']           = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop' ]['createpage']     = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop' ]['createtalk']      = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop' ]['upload']          = true;
```

but how to add a user to this group 'sysop', i am unable to see this group in special page
'User rights management' even after login with 'bureaucrat' user.

can anybody help me..?

Comment: I think i got my answer. Yes sysop is a default admin group.
To create new custom group, i just need to replace sysop with some other name in above code.

Comment: OK, turned my comment into an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration is indeed on wiki.

1. You go to the user on the wiki. For example https://wiki.domain.tld/wiki/User:SomeUser
2. There is a User rights management in the left link menu
3. This links drive you to the https://wiki.domain.tld/wiki/Special:UserRights/SomeUser special page, where you can add him to a group.

Who can add or remove people to which groups can also be customized by the wgAddGroups and wgRemoveGroups settings.

**Relevant links**

- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Assigning_permissions
- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:%24wgAddGroups
- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:%24wgRemoveGroups

Answer (score 0):

Note that the user group `sysop` is *not* a custom group — it's the standard user group for [MediaWiki admins](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aAdministrators), and it is listed as "administrator" in Special:UserRights (assuming that your wiki is in English, and that you haven't customized the label by editing the page MediaWiki:group-sysop-member).

I believe the disparity between the internal and the user-visible name of the group is due to historical reasons: users in the group were originally called sysops, before it was later decided that the term "administrator" would be more easily understood and would better reflect their actual role on a typical wiki.

Anyway, if you want to create a new, custom user group, you need to choose an internal ID for it which is not one of the standard ones (`*`, `user`, `autoconfirmed`, `bot`, `sysop` or `bureaucrat`).  Technically, the *user-visible* name of the group can be anything, even the same as the name of some other group.  To change the user-visible name of the group, you need to edit three MediaWiki pages on your wiki, named as follows (where "*ID*" stands for the internal ID of your group):

- MediaWiki:group-*ID* — the name of the group as a whole, e.g. "Administrators",
- MediaWiki:group-*ID*-member — a name describing a single member of the group, e.g. "administrator", and
- MediaWiki:grouppage-*ID* — the name of a page on your wiki describing the group's role, e.g. "Project:Administrators".